# Provider state becomes empty after screen is loaded first time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

When my app is first loaded, It takes City data stored on sharedpreference and stores in my provider. City value is stored as expected (I tested by printing them in console). But the page loads again for some reason and all my provider state value becomes null. This happens only when I load the app for the first time. I have another screen that has exact same logic and it works fine.
I know Provider and hot reloads are working as they should and its my code that has the issue, I'm new to flutter and any help will be really appreciated. Below are my code - Please feel free to ask for any clarification in the code.

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider( //I have few more providers, removed here to reduce code
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: MyLocation(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: MyColors.myColor2,
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        ),
        home: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

HomeScreen.dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routName = '\homescreen';

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool _isInit = true;
  Future getLoc;

  Future<void> _setCurrentLocation(BuildContext context) async {
    print('calling setcurrent location');
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!prefs.containsKey('locationData')) {
      print("no location data");
      await Provider.of<MyLocation>(context).setCurrentLocation();
    } else {
      print("location data exists");
      final extractedLocationData =
          json.decode(prefs.getString('locationData')) as Map<String, Object>;
      final savedCity = extractedLocationData['city'];
      final savedParentCity = extractedLocationData['parentCity'];
      print("saved city:" + savedCity + " parentcity:" + savedParentCity);
      await Provider.of<MyLocation>(context, listen: false)
          .setUpdatedLocation(savedCity, savedParentCity);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = FloatingSearchBarController();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      _setCurrentLocation(context);
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  FloatingSearchBarController controller;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _getCities(BuildContext context, String keyword) async {
    await Provider.of<SearchedCities>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchAndSetSearchHistory(keyword);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("refreshed homescreen build");
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(//appbar code),
      body:Center(
              child: Text(
            Provider.of<MyLocation>(context).city == null
                ? "Value is still NULL!!!"  
                : "Value is not null!",   //this is printed for a second and screen reloads and value becomes null!
          )), 
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Sorry for the messy code! when I update city data using a searchbar (didn't include in the code above to reduce code) it calls same method

```
await Provider.of<MyLocation>(context, listen: false)
              .setUpdatedLocation(savedCity, savedParentCity);
```

Which simply assign 'city' and 'savedCity' and calls notifyListeners(), but this time screen doesn't load twice and provider seemed to retain the value.
I used provider version - 4.0.0

Comment: check wether current location getting in _setCurrentLocation

Comment: Yes it does, I printed them in console. It works for the first time and whole widget reloads again making provider null. Guess I need to look for solutions on how to retain provider state on hot reload. I saw few solutions but none of them worked so far. May be due to my lack of knowledge on the topic.